# Is this definition of a converging sequence well-posed?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am currently reading about convergence of sequences in a calculus textbook. The textbook introduces this topic with a definition of what a converging sequence is. However, before I read through it, I think it is important for me to attempt at defining converging sequences on my own. I was wondering if I could get feedback that could improve my definition. PS: I am not familiar with the math templates of this website, so I apologize if that makes my comment more difficult to read.

My attempt:

A sequence is converging iff:

There exists a natural number N, such that for all natural numbers k, for all natural numbers n<=k and for all natural numbers m < n, abs(a_(N+k-m)-a) < abs(a_(N+k-n)-a).

My though process:

Intuitively, a sequence diverges when the value of abs(a_n-a) jumps at "random" when n gets larger and larger.

However, when a sequence converges, the value d(n) = abs(a_n-a) must get smaller and smaller indefinitely, assuming that n gets larger and larger. However, d(n) gets smaller and smaller only after d(n) "jumps randomly" between different values a certain N number of times. So the actual "convergence" of the sequence only starts when n is larger than N. From that point on, every d(i) must be smaller than any d(i-j), where j<l (must be smaller than any "previous" distance). This is were the "m<n" in my definition above comes from. Thus d(N+k-m) < d(N+k-n) given that m<n.

I hope my poor English is tolerable, and I hope that I have clarified at least somewhat what I was attempting at.

Comment: You can use Mathjax to improve readability.

Comment: +1 : to your posting.  This is interesting thinking.  Your resulting definition is more complicated than the standard definition of convergent sequences, which is:  $\color{\blue}{\text{A sequence} ~\langle a_n\rangle~ \text{converges to a  limit} ~L~ \text{if and only if}~}$ $\color{\blue}{\text{for any} ~\epsilon > 0~ \text{there exists a postive integer} ~N~}$ $\color{blue}{\text{such that for all positive integers} ~n \geq N, ~|a_n - L| < \epsilon}$. ...see next comment

Comment: The idea is that once a small value $~(\epsilon > 0)~$ is chosen, you have a *neighborhood* around the limit $~(L)~$ that is represented by the interval $(L - \epsilon, L + \epsilon).$  Further, given any such neighborhood, there must exist a positive integer $N$, that that every element in the sequence on or after $a_N$ is in this neighborhood. ...see next comment

Comment: So, the standard definition doesn't really care about the behavior of the sequence of elements within the neighborhood.  It only cares that given any (small) neighborhood around $(L)$, there must always exist some specific point in the sequence, where everything on or after that point is in the neighborhood.

Comment: @user2661923 that is a way more elegant definition. I have to ask though, when you talk about the standard definition not caring about the local behavior of the sequence, does that imply that the distance abs(a_n-a) can increase as long as it stays in the epsilon-neighborhood? If so, does that mean that my attempt only captures "special" cases of convergence,  since you then restrict the possible values for N corresponding to each epsilon-neighborhood? By the way, thank you for your great explanation of the standard textbook definition. I struggled with understanding it.

Comment: "...does that imply that the distance abs(a_n-a) can increase as long as it stays in the epsilon-neighborhood?"  **Yes**.  "If so, does that mean that my attempt only captures 'special' cases of convergence?"  I didn't read your post that carefully, but it would not surprise me if the two definitions were equivalent.  Can you construct a sequence that **is convergent**, based on the standard definition, and **is not convergent**, based on your definition?  If so, please very carefully edit your posting to provide such an example.